# How can i add reactions to messages with discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to add a reaction to a message the bot has previously sent, i have this code so far:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reactionmessage(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("test")
    emoji = client.get_emoji(1078793534909452389) # <-- idk why but this code returns the emoji variable as None even though its the emojis id
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

The output

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.
```

2nd Attempt

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reactionmessage(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("test")
    await msg.add_reaction('<:regional_indicator_x:1078793534909452389>')
```

and this time i get the "Unknown Emoji" error.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji
```

I am pretty sure it is not a custom emoji or anything but i still cant make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if it can take default emoji, just start step by step like this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reactionmessage(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("test")
    emoji = ''
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

It should work fine as default emoji don't needs ID's so it won't be hard to make them work.
If it's working then it means it's issue with ID somehow.
Like `client.get_emoji()` returns an Emoji object, not a string. You can convert the Emoji object to a string like this: **str(emoji.id)**.

So check the emote ID once, to get their ID you can do [place your emote here] it will give you the current syntax of it like `:<emoji_name>:<emoji_id>`.

So you can make it work with `client.get_emoji()` like this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reactionmessage(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("test")
    emoji_id = 1078793534909452389 #Make sure this is correct
    emoji = client.get_emoji(emoji_id)
    if emoji is None:
        emoji_str = f'<:{emoji_name}:{emoji_id}>' #To get like this do \[place your emote here]
    else:
        emoji_str = str(emoji.id)
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji_str)
```